# Laratrust: How to get all users where roles are equal to admin and superadmin

Tags: laravel

I'm trying the get the Users where roles are equal to admin and/or superadmin. I tried the code below, I was able to get all users with role provided in the first argument, then ignores the second argument.

For example the code below will display only users with role admin

```
$owners = User::whereRoleIs( ['admin','superadmin])->get();
```

The second code below will only display the users with role superadmin

```
$owners = User::whereRoleIs( ['superadmin','admin])->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

$users = User::whereRoleIs('admin')->orWhereRoleIs('superadmin')->get();